# Explanation of complex evaluation for this Scheme procedure using lambdas

Tags: scope, scheme, racket, evaluation, r5rs

I was wondering how the following code evaluates to 15.

```
((lambda(x y) (+ (x * y) (x + y))) (lambda (a b) (a b b)) 3)
```

I have been looking at it for a while and cannot seem to understand why the evaluation does not result in an error. Could someone provide a detailed step by step instruction on how this evaluates to 15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier to see what is happening if you named the lambdas. For example,

```
(define (f x y)
  (+ (x * y) (x + y)))

(define (g a b)
  (a b b))
```

Then the expression `((lambda (x y) (+ (x * y) (x + y))) (lambda (a b) (a b b)) 3)` becomes:

```
(f g 3)
```

and it evaluates as:

```
(f g 3)
=> (+ (g * 3) (g + 3))
=> (+ (* 3 3) (+ 3 3))
=> (+ 9 6)
=> 15
```